# Does http to https log out a user concrete5

Tags: php, ssl, concrete5

On my Concrete5 website a user sometimes gets logged out right after logging in when they view a checkout page with https in the url (SSL). None of the other pages have SSL (https in url), not even the login. Is it possible that logging in non-ssl then visiting a page with SSL would log out the user?

Comment: I think this is a cookie thing.  In a pinch, I "solved" this at one point by just forcing SSL for all traffic, but if I had more time, I would look at the scope of the cookies.

Comment: I think you might be right. I didn't enable SSL accross the whole site, but all of the pages from login to checkout and I am no longer getting an error right now.